# how to feed the data from WEBAPI JSON to FullCalendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, fullcalendar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({


            url: 'http://localhost/CalendarAPI/api/calendar/'
    })

    });
    </script>
```

I want to feed the calendar data from WebAPI Json. When I click on the above link I can see the JSON data and I can download the well formatted JSON data.

Need help in feeding the above JSON to the FullCalender JQuery plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Your js code should be like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   url: '/api/ControllerName/GetEvents/'
})
```

GetEvents - an action name.

Your model for events should be like this:

```
public class EventModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? end { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public bool allDay { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller create an action (GetEvents) with code like this:

```
public IEnumerable<EventModel> GetEvents()
    {
        //data from database
        CalendarEntities _db = new CalendarEntities();
        var events = _db.Events.ToList();
        IEnumerable<EventModel> listEvents = events.Select(_event => new EventModel
        {
            id = _event.Id,
            title = _event.Caption,
            start = _event.TimeStart,
            end = _event.TimeEnd,
            allDay = _event.AllDay
        });
        return listEvents;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of fullcalendar is really good, just take a look: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/

You have several ways to include the data from your script. The easiest way is:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```

You can also use an extended form, to pass more options:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                custom_param1: 'something',
                custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
            textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
        }

        // any other sources...

    ]

});
```

Comment: Yes I made the corrections as follows:events: 'http://localhost/CalendarAPI/api/calendar/'

Comment: events: [{"title":"event1","start":"2012-12-05 13:13:10","end":"2012-12-05 13:13:10"},{"title":"event2","start":"2012-12-05 13:13:10","end":"2012-12-05 13:13:10"},{"title":"event3","start":"2012-12-05 13:13:10","end":"2012-12-05 13:13:10"}]
the above statement makes an entry in my calendar.        But when I change the code to    events: http://myPCName/CalendarAPI/api/calendar/' it is not making the entry in the calendar.     The URL is producing the JSON data what I pasted here. Why calendar data is not getting displayed when I call the URL. Why?

Comment: You should post your script what produces the json. I have no clue about .net, but maybe there is the problem and someone can help you.